# Laravel Excel need to export multiple selected record

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, phpexcel

I can't export multiple record from my table on excel, using VueJs and Laravel. I send selected record from VueJs to Laravel and I can export all record if I do a function like this on controller.

```php
public function export(Job $jobs) {
  $jobsArray = explode(',', $job);
  return (new JobsExport($jobsArray))->download('job.xlsx');
}
```

But I have a table with some relationships and like this I can export only `job` model record not relations. So I have done something like this :

```php
// Laravel controller
public function export(Job $jobs) {
  // $jobsArray = explode(',', $job);
  // return (new JobsExport($jobsArray))->download('job.xlsx');
        
  return Excel::download(new JobsExport($jobs), 'jobs.xlsx');
}
```

```php
// jobExport
class JobsExport implements WithStyles, FromCollection, WithMapping, WithHeadings {
    use Exportable;
    
    private $jobs;

    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        return [
            // Style the first row as bold text.
            1    => [
                'font' => [
                    'bold' => true, 
                    'color' => ['rgb' => '695CFE']
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function __construct(Job $jobs)
    {
        $jobs->load('templates', 'teams');
        $this->jobs = $jobs;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        // dd($this->jobs->jobsExport());
        return $this->jobs->jobsExport($this->jobs);
    }

    public function map($jobsExport): array
    {
        // dd($jobsExport->templates->first()->template_name);
        return [
            $jobsExport->id,
            $jobsExport->templates->implode('template_name', ', '),
            $jobsExport->job_description,
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */ 
    public function headings():array
    {
        return[
            'Id',
            'Template',,
            'Description',
        ];
    } 
}
```

Job Model

```
public function jobsExport($jobs)
    {
        $job = $jobs->id;
        return Job::with(['jobtypes', 'templates', 'teams', 'clients'])
            ->when($job, function ($query, $job) {
                $query->where('id', $job);
            })
            ->get();
    }
```

And like this I can export relationships but now I have another problem: I can't export multiple record, I mean if I select multiple record I can export only one of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel-Excel export relationship data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421841/laravel-excel-export-relationship-data)

Comment: NO. I have tryed but the problem is on modal method. Export only one record. I want to export all record i select

Comment: because you have ``type hinted`` the parameter to be ``Job`` type instead of an array. Change ``export(Job $jobs)`` to ``export($jobs)`` and pass your data array to the method and it should work.

Comment: @OMiShah Okay then, i just have done what you suggest, and on controller really i get only element what i select from front-end. But now on `JobExport` i get this error `Argument 1 passed to App\Exports\JobsExport::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\Job, array given, called in`  what should i do now. Really i have searched a lot but no result